# Death certificate from 1910

Tags: 1910s, cause-of-death

My great-grandfather died in 1910, and I'm trying to figure out the cause of death. It looks like "Nussisplexie" (hand written) but could be Neuris, or something similar. Underneath the cause of death line is "a slowly progressive hemorrhage" Any ideas out there?

Comment: Welcome to the Genealogy & Family History SE! Do you have a picture of the death certificate? It might be easier trying to decipher the actual text.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! What country is your certificate from? Certificates from the US sometimes have a numerical code on them that indicate cause of death.  See this article for an example. If you see a number, please edit your question and include it. If you include an image, you don't need to upload the entire certificate -- just a snippet of the section with cause of death will do. https://familyhistorydaily.com/free-genealogy-resources/icd-codes-death-certificates-genealogy/

Comment: The cert is from Cook Co, Illinois. Don't know how to add a photo. Only # on it is Register # 3433

Comment: Click on "edit" underneath your question and then look in the toolbar for "Image". That will let you upload a picture of the death certificate.